# How do I parameterize the django url using router.register?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am newbie in Django. So this might be a trivial question.

I have been been building urlpatterns as following

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('posts', views.PostViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

This creates URLs like `api/posts` and so on.

Now, I am trying to add a voting model to this.. For which I want to create URL like

`api/posts/<id>/vote`

But I don't want to create a path like

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('posts/<int:pk>/vote', views.SomeView)
]
```

Is there a way to do this via `router.register` way?

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#routing-for-extra-actions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First You will define default router same way as you defined.

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('posts', views.PostViewSet, basename='posts')
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls))
]
```

Then define Serializer class as you needed.

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Post

class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
```

Now define the custom method of `vote` inside `PostViewSet` with Allowed HTTP methods.

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import viewsets, status
from rest_framework.decorators import action
from .models import Post
from .serializers import PostSerializer


class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PostSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=['Get'])
    def vote(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = Post.objects.filter(pk=pk)
        serializer = PostSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Now you will be able to access the vote with your desired URL as `api/posts/<pk>/vote`